# Why do I keep getting this error for my bridging Header in Xcode 7: Bridging Header does not exsist?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, bridging-header

I updated my Xcode to version 7 and now I get this error saying the bridging header doesnt exist. It tells me that its supposed to be in the /users/desktop/apps/projectname/projectname-bridging-header.h. I checked in the file and its there but xcode still gives me an error. Has anyone had this problem before and know how to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: remove old one and create new one. Hope it helps.

Comment: I did that it still doesn't work.

Comment: Do you change it's  path from Build Settings?

Comment: yes i put projectname-bridging-header-h

Comment: I just made another bridiging header and deleted the old one and I still get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work there was a problem in the Framework Search Paths. I had to add the destination for one of my ad networks.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new bridging file with a different name and link to that.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I don't get it the bridging header file does exist and xcode is telling me it doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your build folder (Product menu, hold down option to reveal it).

I experienced issues with cocoapods 'useframeworks!' and the build folder was being used, so even after removing it and using an objc version of the library, no matter what I did the bridging header was broken.

Comment: can you update your question with the actual error as a screenshot please?